# How to convert a Microsoft SQL Server CE file (.sdf) to Postgres 9.6 /pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-compact

I have a database file `data.sdf` that I want to import into PgAdmin 4. I've considered using pgloader but the file format does not seem to be accepted. Does anybody have any hints on how I might go about making this work?

Comment: You'll need a Windows tool - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375118/how-to-open-sdf-files). Can't do it directly from pgloader!

Answer (score 1):

You can use my tools to script data and schema as SQL Server compatible scripts, and if required tweak those to run with Postgress: http://erikej.github.io/SqlCeToolbox/